# XmlDocument.load outputs System.IO.FileNotFoundException when debugging on device, but in the simulator files are found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am running Visual studio Xamarin on apple MacOS. In the project I,m trying to load an XML file from the project's Resource folder. It loads in the simulator but not when debugging on device.

public class PrvdrsXMLLoader
    {

```
    List<Provider> providers;
    XmlDocument doc;

    public PrvdrsXMLLoader(String fileName)
    {
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(fileName);
        providers = new List<Provider>();
    }
```

}
[System.IO.FileNotFoundException error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2rg0.png)

[Resources folder including the xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDF6q.png)

When choosing a simulator, the files are found and the load function is executed. I have changed the file name and the extension to lowercase but it didn't help.

The build Action for the resource files are set to BundleResource.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: check your casing - the simulator file system is NOT case sensitive, but the device file system IS case sensitive

Comment: The file name and extension is in lower case. Do you mean the whole path must be in lower case? how can I do this?

Comment: nm my previous comment, the code you are using will load a file from the root of your app, not the resources folder.  You need to move the file from resources to your project's root and mark it as build action == content

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I have placed the files exactly under the project name and checked in the project folder that it is not in the resource folder but in the project file. It is also weird that I have deleted all xml files related to the project in visual studio and checked in the project folder that they are deleted, but the simulator is still able to find the xml fils and execute. I think there might be some folder containing the files that I am not aware of. the MacOS search result only shows the project file ".csproj" when I search for folder name like "filename.xml".

Comment: @Jason Thank you so much. Now I understand that replacing the files location from the project does not actually change it in tile directory. I manually copied the files to the root document. Now it is solved and run on the device.